# ionic v4 hidden radio icon on ion-radio

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic4

Actually i need to style ionic radio component like this
[image]

in ionic 3 i can style ion-radio with override css style

```
.radio-md .radio-icon{
    display: none;
}
.item-md{
    border: 1px solid color($colors,divider);
    border-radius: 6px;
}
.item-radio-checked{
    border: 1px solid color($colors,primary);
}
```

i don't have idea with ionic 4.

**how to style ion-radio using ionic v4 ?**

Comment: You cant do this in ionic 4.. The styling of the component itself can be done only with the css variables

Answer (score 6):

You cannot remove the radio icon. But you can set it's color to transparent.

```
ion-radio{
--color:transparent;
--color-checked: transparent;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with Ionic 4.

Unlike ionic 3 components, ionic 4 components are built using [Web components](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components) via [Stencil.js](https://stenciljs.com/docs/introduction). These components are designed such that external css styles do not affect the component itself. Some styling options are provided using [css 4 variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables). These can be set externally for the component.

In case of `ion-radio`, the only styling options provided are [color properties](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/radio#css-custom-properties).

```
ion-radio{
    --color:#222
}
```

Further reading :[setting ionic variables](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/css-variables#setting-values).

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this by adding width and height to 0 on ion-radio